# How can I configure Eclipse to save console out for my build?

Tags: eclipse, console, compiler-warnings

I specifically only want console out for Building my code, which is primarily C++. Every search for this leads me to configuring Run Configuration(s) to output the console. I'm not trying to RUN my program, just want the additional detail from console-out when I build and get warnings, some of which I'm not getting filepath info in the "Problems" window. Thanks!

Comment: Build of what? Which programming language? The Java build doesn't use the console at all.

Comment: @greg-449 it's C++ mostly. I'll update my question

Answer (score 0):

This might already be set up by default. It was for me, once I found the solution I realized this. Check if the following filename exists:

```
<workspace_name>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/global-build.log
```

If it's there, you might already be setup with build output saved to a file. It should be saved in this file. If you don't have this file, and/or you want to change the file location, do the following: click Window context menu->Preferences. Expand the triangle next to C/C++ on the left sidebar, then under that sub-menu, expand the triangle next to the Build menu, then click Logging. Inside the Logging window, ensure the checkbox next to Enable global build logging is checked, then click the Change... button next to the Log file location text box and select your log file. (In Linux, this part may not be so easy if you don't have a log file already touched. In this case, navigate to the directory in which you want to save your log file, then click the button in the top left that looks like a piece of paper with a pencil over it (when hovering over this button it says "Type a file name"), and then type the name of the log file you wish to use. Click Ok.) Then in the Preferences window, click Apply and/or Ok. Next time you build, this log file should be populated automatically with your Console output.